# Function returning pointer to function pointer

Tags: c++, c

can you define function pointer return integer pointer?
answer is yes. and it should be like this---->

```
integer*(*function)();
```

and my question is , can you define function pointer return function pointer?
if answer is no! teach me please.
if answer is yes, tell me how please.

Comment: @alk That's why I removed the comment :P ...

Comment: Do you want C or C++? There are almost always techniques one might use in C++ that are invalid in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef int * (* (* FP)(void))(void);
```

This defines `FP` to be a type that represents a function pointer to a function returning a function pointer to a function returning a pointer to `int`. All function (types) involved take no arguments.

Answer (score 7):

Of course you can.  The easiest and most readible way is to have an intermediate `typedef`, something like this:

```
typedef int* (*pFunc)(void);
```

and then it's simply:

```
typedef pFunc (*pFuncRetFunc)(void);
```

Comment: That is not valid syntax, it needs to be `typedef int* (*pFunc_t)(void);`.

Comment: Also, in POSIX (at least), typedefs ending in _t are reserved, so its usually best to avoid them.

Comment: or you could just use an [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) as your return type... and be C++ style.

Comment: Still the wrong syntax for defining the function-pointer type.

Comment: @Mgetz: `std::function` has extra overhead compared to a simple function pointer. C++ style is to avoid paying for what you don't need.

Comment: @JeremyWest thanks changed answer to be POSIX compliant

Comment: @MikeSeymour get a modern compiler, and that overhead is gone, I'll take clarity of code over mindless mantra.

Comment: @Mgetz: However modern the compiler, type erasure has a cost (in this case, an extra level of indirection on the function call). If you don't need that, then `std::function` adds a cost but no benefits. Avoiding unnecessary costs is not "mindless mantra".